# Perl Excel::Writer::XLSX formula not calculating when workbook is opened

Tags: perl, excel, xlsx

I am writing a formula to an xlsx using Excel::Writer::XLSX.

When I open the workbook with Excel, there is a 0 in the cell with the formula.

The Calculation Options in Excel is set to Automatic. Clicking on the "Calculate now" button or pressing F9 fails to do anything.

Pressing CTRL+Alt+F9 works.

Is there any way to make sure the formula is calculated when the workbook is opened?

EDIT: Cell contents example "=A3+A4".

Comment: Is it a UserDefined Function?

Comment: It is a simple calculation "=A3+A4". The workbook opens fine but the cell containing the function/calculation displays a 0. If I click in the cell, the formula bar shows "=A3+A4". If I click in the formula bar and then hit enter, the calculation is performed. The calculation is also performed when I do a Ctrl+Alt+F9.

Comment: How did you assign that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue in early versions of Excel 2007 which affects Excel::Writer::XLSX files in this way.

Applying the latest Excel or Office Service packs should fix it.

If not let me know.

Comment: Thanks John. I am using version 12.0.6554.5001 of MSO.DLL and that seems to be somewhere between SP2 and SP3 versions of MS 2007. I will try open the file with a later version if I can find one and post back.

Answer (score 2):

Excel::Writer::XLSX has a $worksheet->write_formula method that can be used as a workaround. It has a value field to store the result of the formula if you have a version of Excel that is affected by John's answer above.